# VS 2019 .gitignore doesn't remove the error "db.lock permission denied"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to do `git add .` on my project but this certain error always appear.
I have looked at every possible way on how to fix this and the top results always show to add .gitignore and still the error `open(".vs/*****/v16/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"): Permission denied` is showing. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Close visual studio?

Comment: @Julian have restarted multiple times and even restarted the pc.

Comment: did you commit it? Adding it to `.gitignore` won't remove it from the repository.

Comment: @Todd I am trying to add my codes to the staging area and i think its the first step before committing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The top results always show to add `.gitignore` and still the error

That would work only if `.vs/` is *not* already tracked by Git.

Check first:

```
cd C:\path\to\my\repository
git rm --cached -r .vs/
echo .vs/>>.gitignore
```

The `git add` command should now work:

```
git add .
```

Comment: I've tried doing it on git bash on the folder that has my project, but it says that C: Windows: command not found

Comment: @JhazeFranco That just means the PATH was not properly set. Open a new CMD, and try again. I have edited the answer to add double quotes, in order to take into account paths with spaces. Make sure to use the correct path to Git.

Comment: `git rm --cached -r .vs/` worked without having to go through the `%PATH%`

Comment: @JhazeFranco I though it would: as long as it was tracked by Git, adding it to the .gitignore would change nothing. I have rewritten the answer to better emphasize that.

Answer (score 2):

for this if you work in visual studio when adding files in to git using git bash,first close visual studio. then use git bash to add files to github.It works for me.